# How to host simple REST service using .NET core

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, wcf, .net-core, webhttpbinding

I'm trying to migrate WCF (WebHttpBinding) to .NET core. Because, WebHttpBinding is not available in coreWCF.

Here my server code to host the REST service:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
var app = builder.Build();
app.Urls.Add("http://localhost:9000/MyService");
app.MapGet("/Test", () => "Hello World!");
app.Run();
```

Here my client code to call the service:

```
using HttpClient client = new();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
var reply = await client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:9000/MyService/Test");
```

The client code works good if the service is developed using WCF (WebHttpBinding). However, above server-code does not work.

How should I create REST service, so that the client-code can access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try creating the service like this?

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();
app.Urls.Add("http://localhost:9000");
app.MapGet("/MyService/Test", () => "Hello World!");

app.Run();
```

The URL should not contains paths.